# Python 3 - Tcl/Tk how to get image from filedialog and display it?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to select a file from the filedialog and have the picture shown in the GUI

```
def onOpen():
    """ Ask the user to choose a file and change the update the value of photo"""
    photo= get(filedialog.askopenfilename())

photo2 = PhotoImage(filedialog=photo)
#how do I get photo2 to work and get button to display the picture?
button = Button(root, image=photo2, text="click here", command=onOpen).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve can be done in three steps:

- get the path of the picture chosen by the user
  `filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename()`
- create the `PhotoImage`
- change the image of the button using the `configure` method

In addition, you need to make the variable containing the `PhotoImage` global so that it is not garbage-collected.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def onOpen():
    global photo
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file=filename)
    button.configure(image=photo)

root = tk.Tk()

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="/path/to/initial/picture.png")
button = tk.Button(root, image=photo, command=onOpen)
button.grid()

root.mainloop()
```